# MockK: capture() intercepts calls that do not match the full list of parameters in the enclosing verify()

Tags: kotlin, mockk

In the below example I would expect capture() to engage only when the full list of parameters to verify() matches, however the opposite seems to be true.

Is this behavior intended?

```
interface ExternalService {
    fun doIt(doCapture: Boolean, captureCandidate: String)
}

class VerifyCaptureDemo {

    val externalService: ExternalService = mockk(relaxed = true)

    @Test
    fun demo() {
        externalService.doIt(false, "noCaptureExpected")
        externalService.doIt(true, "captureThis")

        val capturedValues = mutableListOf<String>()
        verify(exactly=1) { externalService.doIt(false, any()) }
        verify(exactly=1) { externalService.doIt(true, capture(capturedValues)) }
        assertEquals(1, capturedValues.size) //java.lang.AssertionError:: Expected: 1, Actual: 2
    }

}
```

Comment: This was fixed in v1.13.3 https://github.com/mockk/mockk/releases/tag/1.13.3